# Which JS to use and how to implement for image popup from SVG text?

Tags: javascript, svg, popupwindow

I've got this code for a highly cropped and simplified graphic I want to use for navigation:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="540">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0 {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #BF2236;
      stroke-width: 12.3807;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      stroke-miterlimit: 3.994;
    }

    .st1 {
      fill: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .st2 {
      fill: #231F20;
    }

    .label {
      font-family: PaddingtonPlain, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
      font-size: 25px;
      fill: #0054A6;
    }

    .label:hover {
      fill: #F15A22;
      font-size: 30px
    }
  </style>

  <path d="M372.7 442.7v-70.6c0-10.3-3.9-20.6-11.8-28.4-7.3-7.3-17.3-11.8-28.5-11.8H229.8" class="st0" />
  <g id="int_x5F_leeds">
    <path d="M337.8 337.3c0 7.6 6.2 13.8 13.8 13.8 7.6 0 13.8-6.2 13.8-13.8 0-7.6-6.2-13.8-13.8-13.8-7.6 0-13.8 6.2-13.8 13.8"
      class="st1" />
    <path d="M351.6 320.7c9.2 0 16.6 7.4 16.6 16.6 0 9.1-7.4 16.5-16.6 16.5-9.1 0-16.5-7.4-16.5-16.5 0-9.2 7.4-16.6 16.5-16.6m11.1 16.6c0-6.1-5-11.1-11.1-11.1s-11 5-11 11.1 4.9 11 11 11 11.1-4.9 11.1-11z"
      class="st2" />
  </g>

  <a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_leeds.htm">
    <text id="label_x5F_ls" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 374.402 344.976)" cursor="default" class="label">Leeds</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Also here, in case of viewing problems:
https://codepen.io/SteveLovell74/pen/ervYyQ

I think this would be adequate, but ideally, I'd like to add a popup image at a fixed position on hover. Can anyone advise on what code to use and how I'd implement it? I'm finding lots of examples that don't seem to help me with this.

I'm trying to replicate something like this (which I paid someone to make interactive, but I need to edit and control this myself:

http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/svg_map.htm

Many thanks.

Comment: You could do it with only CSS (with `:hover` and the sibling selector `+`) but it would mean that you have an *img* tag in your html for each popup. Or you could use javascript to make a fixed element visible on mouse over with events. This would mean that all your popup images would be in css and switched over time. Have you tried these options or do you have a preference/technology limitations ?

Comment: Thanks. Using CSS would be preferable, as not using JS would be one less thing I have to try and understand or implement. I have literally no idea about how I would do that with CSS though. I made my own basic website and I have a very hard time learning things like this. So treat me like an idiot. :)

Answer (score 1):

After some tries I figured out a possible CSS-only workaround for your problem. Note that it looks a bit tricky but is still possible without any Javascript.

I've kept your code structure but removed useless elements for this demonstration. The trick here resides in the **css**:

- `.popup-trigger:hover + .popup-image` makes possible to add rules for the first element matching `.popup-image` after `.popup-trigger` element only when hovered. (note that they must have the same parent).
- for more information, see [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and the [browser compatibility table](https://caniuse.com/#search=adjacent%20sibling%20selector)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="400">
<style type='text/css'>

 /* By default popups are invisible */
 .image-popup{
  opacity: 0;
 }
 
 /* When trigger is :hover, the next element if '.image-popup' will be visible */
 .popup-trigger:hover + .image-popup{
  opacity: 1;
 }

</style>

  
<!-- Label 1 -->
<a class='popup-trigger'>
  <text x="200" y="100" cursor="default" class="label">Label 1</text>
</a>
<!-- Popup image 1 -->
<image class='image-popup' xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Greater_London_UK_location_map_2.svg/180px-Greater_London_UK_location_map_2.svg.png" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  
  

<!-- Label 2 -->
<a class='popup-trigger'>
  <text x="200" y="200" cursor="default" class="label">Label 2</text>
</a>

<!-- Popup image 2 -->
<image class='image-popup' xlink:href="https://www.aifsabroad.com/images/maps/england/map_england.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks great. Thank you so much for your help. It's greatly appreciated. I'll try picking it apart and applying to my example, then I'll work on the full intended navigation. This is a great start. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I eventually managed yo wrangle this to get exactly what I wanted. Thanks to all that gave advice.

Here's the code in case it helps anyone else:

```
<div class="map_container">


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="800" height="540">
<style type="text/css">
.map_container
{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 540px;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
}

.path_x0020_red{fill:none;stroke:#BF2236;stroke-width:12.3807;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.994;} .path_x0020_yellow{fill:none;stroke:#FAA61A;stroke-width:12.3807;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.994;} .path_x0020_green{fill:none;stroke:#39B54A;stroke-width:12.3807;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.994;} .path_x0020_blue{fill:none;stroke:#44C8F5;stroke-width:12.3807;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.994;} .st0{fill:none;stroke:#FAA61A;stroke-width:12.3807;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.994;} 
.st1{fill:none;stroke:#BF2236;stroke-width:12.3807;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:3.994;}
.st2{fill:#FAA61A;}
.st3{fill:#BF2236;}
.st4{fill:#39B54A;}
.st5{fill:#44C8F5;} 
.st6{fill:#FFFFFF;}
.st7{fill:#231F20;} 
.st8{fill:#0054A6;}
.st9{font-family:PaddingtonPlain;}
.st10{font-size:24.7614px;}
.st11{enable-background:new ;}
.label{font-family:PaddingtonPlain,"Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;font-size:25px;fill:#0054A6;}
.label:hover {fill:#F15A22;font-size:25px} 
.image-popup{opacity: 0;}
.popup-trigger:hover + .image-popup{opacity: 1;}
.map_border{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ccc;}
</style>

<path id="path_x5F_b_x5F_1" d="M478.8 43.4v150c0 10.3-3.9 20.6-11.8 28.5L344 345" class="path_x0020_blue"/>
<path id="path_x5F_y_x5F_2" d="M540.8 389l24.7-24.7c7.3-7.3 17.3-11.8 28.5-11.8h136.9" class="st0"/>
<path id="path_x5F_y_x5F_1" d="M562.4 367.3l-27.8 27.8c-7.3 7.3-17.3 11.8-28.5 11.8H375" class="path_x0020_yellow"/>
<path id="path_x5F_r_x5F_6" d="M177.2 368.4l24.7-24.7c7.3-7.3 17.3-11.8 28.5-11.8h70.4" class="st1"/>
<path id="path_x5F_r_x5F_5" d="M193 352.6l-36.6 36.6c-7.3 7.3-11.8 17.3-11.8 28.5 0 10.3 3.9 20.6 11.8 28.4l51.4 51.4" class="st1"/>
<path id="path_x5F_r_x5F_4" d="M282.1 515.8h-39.3c-10.3 0-20.6-3.9-28.5-11.8l-9.3-9.3" class="st1"/>
<path id="path_x5F_r_x5F_3" d="M356.5 476.3L328.7 504c-7.3 7.3-17.3 11.8-28.5 11.8h-42.7" class="path_x0020_red"/>
<path id="path_x5F_r_x5F_2" d="M372.7 404.2v39.3c0 10.3-3.9 20.6-11.8 28.5l-9.3 9.3" class="st1"/>
<path id="path_x5F_r_x5F_1" d="M372.7 442.7v-70.6c0-10.3-3.9-20.6-11.8-28.4-7.3-7.3-17.3-11.8-28.5-11.8H229.8" class="st1"/>
<path id="path_x5F_g_x5F_1" d="M606 351.7V201.8" class="path_x0020_green"/>
<path d="M739.4 352.6h-33.3v-6.2h25.3v-8.3h8.1zM739.5 367h-8.1v-8.3h-25.3v-6.1h33.3z" class="st2"/>
<path d="M407.7 472.1h-33.3V466h25.3v-8.3h8zM407.7 486.6h-8v-8.4h-25.3v-6.1h33.3zM351.6 291.4v33.3h-6.1v-25.2h-8.3v-8.1zM366.1 291.4v8.1h-8.4v25.2h-6.1v-33.3zM176.2 304l23.6 23.5-4.4 4.4-17.8-17.9-5.9 5.9-5.7-5.7zM186.4 293.7l5.7 5.8-5.9 5.9 17.9 17.8-4.3 4.3-23.6-23.5zM112.6 386.1l23.6 23.5-4.4 4.4-17.8-17.9-5.9 5.9-5.7-5.7zM122.8 375.9l5.7 5.7-5.9 5.9 17.9 17.8-4.3 4.3-23.6-23.5zM161.2 494.8h33.4v6.1h-25.3v8.3h-8.1zM161.2 480.3h8.1v8.4h25.3v6.1h-33.4zM323.2 365.6l23.6-23.5 4.3 4.3-17.8 17.9 5.9 5.8-5.7 5.8zM313 355.4l5.7-5.7 5.9 5.9 17.9-17.8 4.3 4.3-23.6 23.5z" class="st3"/>
<path d="M606 196.6v33.3h-6.2v-25.2h-8.3v-8.1zM620.4 196.6v8.1h-8.3v25.2H606v-33.3z" class="st4"/>
<path d="M478.9 39.1v33.3h-6.2V47.1h-8.3v-8zM493.3 39.1v8H485v25.3h-6.1V39.1zM463.3 140.3h14.5v8.1h-14.5z" class="st5"/>
<path d="M591.5 242.5H606v8.1h-14.5z" class="st4"/>
<path d="M478.8 73.2h14.5v8.1h-14.5z" class="st5"/><g id="int_x5F_selby">
<circle cx="605.8" cy="352.4" r="16.5"/>
<circle cx="605.8" cy="352.4" r="11.1" class="st6"/></g>
<g id="int_x5F_wake">
<circle cx="360.6" cy="472.1" r="16.5"/>
<circle cx="360.6" cy="472.1" r="11.1" class="st6"/>
</g><g id="int_x5F_leeds">
<circle cx="351.6" cy="337.5" r="16.5"/>
<circle cx="351.6" cy="337.5" r="11.1" class="st6"/></g>
<g id="int_x5F_brad">
<circle cx="208.9" cy="338.6" r="16.5"/>
<circle cx="208.9" cy="338.6" r="11.1" class="st6"/>
</g><g id="int_x5F_kirk_1_">
<circle cx="205.6" cy="494.8" r="16.5"/>
<circle cx="205.6" cy="494.8" r="11.1" class="st6"/></g>
<g id="int_x5F_cald">
<circle cx="144.8" cy="417.8" r="16.5" class="st7"/>
<circle cx="144.8" cy="417.8" r="11.1" class="st6"/></g>

<!-- Selby-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_selby.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_sel" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 574.8 389.016)" cursor="default">Selby</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/selby/400_selby.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Hull-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_hull.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
  <text id="label_x5F_hu" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 743.307 359.782)" cursor="default">Hull</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/hull/400_hull.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Newcastle City-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_newcastle_city.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_ne_x5F_c" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 497.238 72.4)" cursor="default">
<tspan x="0" y="0" cursor="default">Newcastle</tspan>
<tspan x="0" y="22" cursor="default">City</tspan></text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/newcastle_city/400_newcastle_city.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Newcastle-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_newcastle.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
  <text id="label_x5F_ne_1_" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 419.057 33.935)" cursor="default">Newcastle</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/newcastle_full/400_newcastle.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- York City-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_york_city.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_yo_x5F_c" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 493.577 250.423)" cursor="default">York City</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/york_city/400_york_city.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- York-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_york.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_yo_1_" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 578.268 191.003)" cursor="default">York</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/york_full/400_york.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Bygone Leeds-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_leeds.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_ls_x5F_hist" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 315.515 263.888)" cursor="default"><tspan x="0" y="0" cursor="default">Bygone</tspan><tspan x="4.4" y="23" cursor="default">Leeds</tspan></text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/leeds_bygone/400_leeds_hist.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Leeds-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_leeds.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_ls" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 374.402 344.976)" cursor="default">Leeds</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/leeds_full/800_leeds_v4.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Wakefield City-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_wakefield_city.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_wf_x5F_c" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 411.44 481.216)" cursor="default">Wakefield City</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/wakefield_city/400_wakefield_city.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Wakefield -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_wakefield.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_wf" transform="matrix(.922 0 0 1 241.939 462.995)" cursor="default">Wakefield</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/wakefield_full/400_wakefield_orderaround.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Leeds City-->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_leeds.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_ls_x5F_c" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 263.142 381.332)"><tspan x="0" y="0" cursor="default">Leeds</tspan><tspan x="4.1" y="22" cursor="default">City</tspan></text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/leeds_city/400_leeds_city.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Bradford City -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_bradford_city.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_bd" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 110.519 281.962)" cursor="default"><tspan x="0" y="0" cursor="default">Bradford</tspan><tspan x="18.5" y="22" cursor="default">City</tspan></text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/bradford_city/400_bradford_city.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Bradford -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_bradford.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_bd" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 210.096 318.809)" cursor="default">Bradford</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/bradford/400_bradford_orderaround.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="200" />


<!-- Calderdale -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_calderdale.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_cald" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 12.209 427.827)" cursor="default">Calderdale</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/calderdale/400_calderdale_orderaround.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="200" />


<!-- Halifax -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_halifax.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_hx" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 33.388 386.078)" cursor="default">Halifax</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/halifax/400_halifax.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Darlington -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_darlington.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_dl" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 350.095 149.401)" cursor="default">Darlington</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/darlington/400_darlington.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Kirklees -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_kirklees.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
 <text id="label_x5F_kirk" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 225.486 499.993)" cursor="default">Kirklees</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/kirklees/400_kirklees_orderaround.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

<!-- Huddersfield -->
<a xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/orderaround_huddersfield.htm" class="label popup-trigger" >
<text id="label_x5F_hd" transform="matrix(.972 0 0 1 19.986 500.66)" cursor="default">Huddersfield</text></a>
<image class="image-popup" xlink:href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/images/pub_maps/huddersfield/400_huddersfield.png" x="0" y="0" height="200" />

</svg>

</div>
```